# how to multiply two column values using triggers?

Tags: mysql

i have to multiply two column values instantly using triggers
my table will be like

```
+=================================================
energy         power     total
5               5        null
8               4        null
9               6        null
```

i want of total=energy*power;

```
CREATE trigger sum BEFORE INSERT on sample
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.total=NEW.energy*NEW.power
END ;
```

I have an error in line 5

Comment: error in line 5 ..missing semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER multiplier BEFORE INSERT ON sample
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.total = new.energy * new.power;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

More information about trigger syntax and the use of DELIMITER at [trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) in the mysql manual.

Comment: i got syntax error in delimiter, i am using version mysql 5.6.17 is that matters.....

Comment: @vidhyavarshini : use // as delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Use Following Script:

```
CREATE trigger sum BEFORE INSERT on sample

FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.total=NEW.energy*NEW.power ;
```

Remove the `Begin` and `End` tags, it worked for me.